# How to fix flutter image_picker IOS simulator PlatformException(invalid_source, Inv ..) error?

Tags: flutter

`image_picker: ^0.8.7`

and flutter

```
flutter --version
Flutter 3.7.0 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision b06b8b2710 (2 days ago) • 2023-01-23 16:55:55 -0800
Engine • revision b24591ed32
Tools • Dart 2.19.0 • DevTools 2.20.1
```

I get one error like the below every time I select one image from the gallery to upload!!! (In IOS simulator)

```
1)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(invalid_source, Invalid image source., null, null)
#0      ImagePickerApi.pickImage (package:image_picker_ios/src/messages.g.dart:136:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      ImagePickerIOS.getImageFromSource (package:image_picker_ios/image_picker_ios.dart:78:26)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

My code is like this

```
    final _imagePicker = ImagePicker();
    var image = await _imagePicker.pickImage(source: imageSource);
    if (image == null) {
      return;
    }
    // do something with the image
```

PS: I don't have one IOS real device to try the code, and before 2 months with older image picker versions the simulator worked fine and could pick images.
I also read a lot of related questions in which they said to update to last version, not to chose the first image in the gallery etc etc but none worked, therefore I posted the question.

Comment: Did you fix it? I have same error.

Comment: Hi, no I haven't found a fix yet! which is super weird as am looking into the official flutter issues as well and there is no answer yet. Also the provided answer here does not work. I am using real device to test at the moment... If you find a fix please post it as answer here to help all having same issue. If I find answer before you will post it as answer here as well

Comment: I create new project with image_picker: ^0.8.7+2 and add same code it work for me, seems ridiculous but after i clone my project to another Mac and rebuild, it work for me. I don't understand why but it still doesn't work when building from my Mac

Comment: " Starting with version 0.8.1 the iOS implementation uses PHPicker to pick (multiple) images on iOS 14 or higher. As a result of implementing PHPicker it becomes impossible to pick HEIC images on the iOS simulator in iOS 14+. "
I found my problem in here, I use emulator with ios 15.2 so I can't pick photo

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this :

```
final _imagePicker = ImagePicker();
var image = await _imagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
if (image == null) {
  return;
}
```

And add the following key to your `Info.plist` file, located in `<project root>/ios/Runner/Info.plist`:

```
NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am already using `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` and also I am using ImageSource.gallery already